# Splitting String and taking out specific elements in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, string

I have Sample String like this

> "Organisation/Guest/images/guestImage.jpg"

I need to take out Organisation,Guest separately.
I have tried split() but can't get desired output.

Comment: Please post the code you tried.

Comment: Did you try `"Organisation/Guest/images/guestImage.jpg".split('/')` ?

Comment: It works for me.

Comment: Using "Organisation/Guest/images/guestImage.jpg".split('/') I am getting [ 'Organisation', 'Guest', 'images', 'guestImage.jpg' ] in which I can easily get the elements of Array. Thanks Reyon.

Answer (score 2):

```js
var str = "Organisation/Guest/images/guestImage.jpg";
var res = str.split("/");
    
console.log(res[0]);
console.log(res[1]);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use of [String.replace()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp) along with regex

```js
const regex = /Organisation\/|\/Organisation/;

console.log('Organisation/Guest/images/guestImage.jpg'.replace(regex, ''));

console.log('Guest/Organisation/images/guestImage.jpg'.replace(regex, ''));

console.log('Guest/images/guestImage.jpg/Organisation'.replace(regex, ''));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var yourString = "Organisation/Guest/images/guestImage.jpg";

yourString.split('/')
// this returns all the words in an array

yourString[0] // returns Organisation
yourString[1] // returns Guest and so on
```

When you run `.split()` on a string, it will return a new array with all the words in it. In the code I am splitting by the slash `/`

Then I save the new array in a variable. Now you should know we can access array properties like this: `array[0]` where 0 is the first index position or the first word, and so on.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thank you for the code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A proper explanation would greatly improve its [long-term value](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/206345) by describing why this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other similar questions. Please edit your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.

Comment: Thank you for the heads up, I'll do.